# how to add Rich Text box Editor for Wordpress Post

Tags: wordpress, post, richtextbox

I am trying to add the Rich text Box Editor Plugin for a Wordpress post by using [this link](http://www.ternstyle.us/products/plugins/wordpress/wordpress-rich-text-biography).

I tried with different rich text box editor plugins, but it is not displaying the Richtextbox editor to write a post.

Are there any other settings I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use TinyMCE Advanced plugin.

Have a look here: http://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/